# dynamic src in vue with laravel 9

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using laravel 9 (with vite) and vue 2.7 and I need to use dynamic
`:src`

but when I use this

```
<img :src="`../../assets/${path}`" >
```

the url loads perfectly in the DOM but the image doesn't show on the page.

also when i get error message that says `require is not defined` when I use this:

```
<img :src="require(`../../assets/${path}`)" >
```

node v16.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest to check if in your template string the "path" contains the extension of the given image (.png, .gif, .jpg).

Secondly, you should try to place your images inside the public folder in the Laravel Application, since by default, the Vue components will look for the specific resource (in your case images) at that place.

For example if you have something like the code bellow, the Vue component will look for the certain image inside public/images subfolder inside Laravel.

> /public/images

```
<img :src="`/images/${path}.png`" />
```

In your case, the whole path is wrong since it goes outside the Laravel folder/application. You are saying: Go outside public folder, go one more time outside, and than look for the assets folder.

At end /images in the :src means public/images